# Firebase Cloud function GET Request with google-translate-api

Tags: firebase, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-translate

I am new to Node Js trying to create an App translate fr to en. My code work fine when I use it in local node serve or firebase serve, but it didn't work on when i deploy it to Firebase Cloud function.

And also Firebase deploy run but didn't update google API as expected or the word not get translated , it shows "Pls wait" but din't update it
Any help will be appreciated.

**Firebase LOG - Error:**  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND translate.google.com translate.google.com:443
    at /user_code/node_modules/google-translate-api/node_modules/google-translate-token/index.js:103:25
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions'); //in Firebase 

 const functions = require('firebase-functions');


const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
var translator = "Pls Wait";
const translate = require('google-translate-api');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/api', function(req , res) {
   createTranslation();
   res.send(translator);
})


function createTranslation() {
     translate('Ik spreek Engels', {to: 'en'}).then(res => {
            console.log(res.text);
            translator = res.text;
            //=> I speak English
        // players = res.text;
            console.log(res.from.language.iso);
         //   return JSON.parse(res.body).data;;
            //=> nl
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log("ERROR");
            console.log(err);
            console.error(err);
        });
  }


var server = app.listen(function(){

    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;

    if(!host || host === "::"){
        host = "localhost:";
    }

    console.log('API running on http://%s%s', host , port);
});



 exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app); //In Firebase
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set up an arbitrary express server using Cloud Functions.  This doesn't work:

```
var server = app.listen(8081, function() { ... })
```

You have to handle input via one of the triggers defined in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

Also, you can't just start calling methods at global scope and expect them to work:

```
translate(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

Again, you need to think about running your code **in response to triggers** that you define

You started to define an express app that might respond as an HTTPS trigger, but it calls nothing interesting, and sends only static text to the client:

```
const app = express();
app.get('/api', cors(), function(req, res) {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(translator));
})
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app); //In Firebase
```

If you're trying to learn Cloud Functions, you should start with a simple example and add to it, rather than trying to port some existing node app verbatim.

Comment: how can i trigger translate()